# jQuery .next() and .prev() not working as they should!

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get the `.next()` and `.prev()` sibling of an HTML element **without excluding TextNodes**.

I basically need to understand if an element is *directly* sorrounded by `<br>` HTML elements.

This would return true:

```
<br>
<div></div>
<br>
```

This would return false:

```
<br>
Some text
<div></div>
<br>
```

**BUT** this needs to also return true:

```
<br>

<div></div>
<br>
```

The third example basically uses an empty TextNode, or blankspaces, or newlines.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: As a general rule, if you're working *completely* inside jQuery, forget dealing with text nodes, it provides almost zero enhancements over vanilla javascript there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `previousSibling` and `nextSibling` I would say.

If it's of type `TextNode` and the value is falsy go another step.

Comment: You could do `textContent.replace(/\s+/g, '')` on the text node contents before testing them.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code for "next()", "prev()", "parents()", "nextAll", "prevAll", and most others of that sort explicitly skip nodes that aren't elements (type 1).  That behavior isn't optional or alterable without changing the fundamentals of the library.